# When is there a reputation gain for edits?

Tags: support, edits

According to the [What is reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) we receive +2 reputation when a suggested edit is accepted. Does this mean we should gain reputation when:

1. an edit is approved on review?
2. an answer is edited and approved when reviewed?
3. an accepted answer is edited and the review approves the edit?
4. a non-accepted answer is edited, approved on review and subsequently accepted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You only gain reputation for **suggested edits**; any edit you make as a user with 2k+ reputation is not a suggested edit but instead applies immediately and doesn't gain you any reputation.

Suggested edits gain the editor +2 points when the edit is approved (in review or directly by the original post owner) *and* they haven't yet gained 1000 points from edits.

It doesn't matter if the post was an answer or a question, nor does the status of the answer matter in the slightest.

Two things of note:

- For *tag wikis* and *tag wiki excerpts* you need 20k+ points before you can edit those directly.
- If the post you edited is deleted, any reputation earned for edits to that post is lost again. This goes for tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts as well.

Comment: I see! Perhaps the wording for Suggested edits in "What is reputation" should be changed from "suggested edit is approved" to "suggested edit is accepted"?

Comment: As well as if the material you gained rep from is removed, you lose the reputation gained

Comment: @EmilH: I don't see what difference that would make. The suggested edit is accepted because the reviewers approved it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In all the places I've seen, in the context of edits, the SO GUI uses the word "approve" as opposed to "accept", except for on the "What is reputation" page. So this is a *very minor* inconsistency.

Comment: @TylerH: there is no six months rule. You are confusing that with the *60 days* rule, and only for posts you earned a score 3 or more on. Points gained for suggested edits don't fall under that rule.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it didn't apply to edits as well.