# Is the editor (other than questioner or answerer) of a question or an answer benefited / rewarded incentive? If yes - how?

Tags: support, editor

[I answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35410813/). After few hours or so a user edited this answer. What he did was, he just inserted some spaces in the beginning of my answer. That's all, what he did.
Thus, I am asking this question.

My question was not [When is there a reputation gain for edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251312/2173890). but in initial 'do they' get?

Comment: The editor formatted your code as code, which makes it display much more nicely.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe, but as a quick answer: Yes, until they have 2k rep or have earned 1k rep from editing. That user got nothing from it as they have 13k rep, but they _did_ properly format your code so that it showed up on the site as code. It's much easier to read when it's formatted. See the [Editing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) help center page for more about editing on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I take issue with your tone here, though. You make it sound like this person made a minor, insignificant edit just to gain reputation. That was surely not the case. [Your original version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35410813/1) contained code that was unreadable because it was not correctly formatted. [The edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35410813/2) did just add a few spaces, but those spaces caused the code to be formatted *as code*, transforming the answer from an unreadable mess into something useful. You should learn from the edit and format code this way in the future.

Comment: yes Cody Gray. i got it. thanks for all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editors below 2k reputation are awarded 2 reputation for each accepted edit on a non-deleted post. After that they are not awarded anything. In this specific case, the editor did a good thing:

[image]

Which made your text obvious that it should be treated as "code" and formatted.

Comment: Uhh - are you still on Windows 2000 ? That scrollbar looks horrible..

Comment: That is a *real* scrollbar. The non-invisible kind that you can actually see and manipulate.

Comment: @JonasCz It's functional. Point.